# How to determine SSL cert expiration date from a PEM which have a lot of certificats concatenated on one file (pem)?

Tags: openssl

How to determine SSL cert expiration date from a PEM which have a lot of certificats concatenated on one file (pem) ?

Example:

```
# cat cert.pem

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 

... 

-----END CERTIFICATE----- 

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 

... 

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The command below, give me only the end date of the first certificate on the file

```
# openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -enddate
notAfter=Sep 26 16:12:59 2019 GMT
```

Have you any idea to get end date of all certificates (one by one) using shell?

Comment: Have a look at the `csplit` command that can split a file based on a pattern.

Comment: Yes, i know csplit, but i search solution without spliting file. the most, using openssl. thanks Patrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As found out in https://serverfault.com/questions/391396/how-to-split-a-pem-file#676968 something like that works:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile cert.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -text | grep -E '(Subject:|Not After)'
```

But the subject comes after the date.

Otherwise you need to do some shell glue using `sed`, `awk` or `perl` for example.

Comment: awk shell glue to replace grep: `awk '/^Certificate:/ && (NR>1) {printf "%s%s", subj, date; subj=date=""}  /^ *Subject:/ {subj=$0 "\n"}  /^ *Not After *:/ {date=$0 "\n"}  END {printf "%s%s", subj, date}'`